# Search for the time in the array when compare with current time

Tags: php, arrays

I am stored the list of times in the arrays. I would like to search for the time to see if the time in the arrays that comes close to my current time.

Example: My current time is `01:16` so in the arrays there are `01.00`, `01:30`, `02:00` and `05:00`. If my current time show `01:16` or greater than, the closest time would be `01:00` so I want to get the integer value which it is `3`. If my current time show `01:30` or greater than the time in the array `01:30`, the correct time would be `01:30` so I want to get the value `3`. If my current time show `02:00` or greater than the time in the array `02:00`, the correct time would be `02:00` so I want to get the value `4`. Same for `05.00`..etc.

Here is the code:

```
function get_shows($day,$channel_id, DateTime $dt, $today = false) 
{

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT => '',
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 5,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
   ));

   $date = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
   $tz = $dt->getTimezone();

   $now = new DateTime('now', $tz);
   $today = $now->format('Y-m-d');
   $shows = array();
   $url = 'https://www.example.com?date=' . $date;
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   $body = curl_exec($ch); //get the page contents
   $channel_row = $row_channels[0][0]; // Woksepp: 0 = First row.
   $pattern23 = "/<a class=\"prog\" href=\"(.*?)\">.*?<span class=\"time\">(.*?)<\/span>.*?<span class=\"title\" href=\"\#\">(.*?)<\/span>.*?<span class=\"desc\">(.*?)<\/span>/s";
    preg_match_all($pattern23, $channel_row, $d);
   $show_times = $d[2];

   if($day==0)
   {
      //check if my current time is close to the time in the arrays then set the $flag value
     //$flag = $i
   }
}
?>
```

Here is the results

```
Array ( [0] => 23:10 [1] => 00:40 [2] => 01:00 [3] => 01:30 [4] => 02:00 [5] => 05:00 
[6] => 06:00 [7] => 08:00 [8] => 08:30 [9] => 09:00 [10] => 10:00 
[11] => 10:30 [12] => 11:00 [13] => 11:25 [14] => 13:30 [15] => 13:55 
[16] => 16:00 [17] => 16:25 [18] => 16:55 [19] => 19:00 [20] => 19:55 
[21] => 22:15 [22] => 22:30 [23] => 23:30 [24] => 01:30 )
```

What I am expecting to do is to check if the time in the arrays that come close to the current time so I want to get the integer value to set the `$flag` with the value just like this `$flag = $i`.

Can you please show me an example how I can comparing the times in the arrays with my current time as it come close by so I want to get the integer value?

Comment: "*the arrays there are `01.00`, `01:30`, `02:00` and `05:00`. If my current time show `01:16` or greater than, the closest time would be `01:00`*" - 1:30 is closed to 1:16 (14mins apart) than 1:00 is (16mins).

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a nifty function [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) which will let you translate a string to a unix timestamp, which makes it so much easier to compare two times.

Then you will just have to iterate over your array, and find the time with the least difference (absolute value of current time minus the time in the array) and save the array key for that particular time in a variable.

```
$currentTime  = time();
$minTimeValue = PHP_INT_MAX;
$minTimeKey   = -1;

foreach ($array as $key => $time) {
    $thisTimeDifference = abs($currentTime - strtotime($time));
    if ($thisTimeDifference < $minTimeValue) {
        $minTimeKey = $key;
        $minTimeValue = $thisTimeDifference;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so how I can use `$flag` to set the value when my current time is equal or greater than the times in the array?